# using char, cast to an int as array index to store frequency of "chars" in a textfile

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Iam writing a simple program to store number of occurrence's of the various symbols in a text file. I am reading from this file using fgetc() and a file pointer. one char at a time. i set up my array outside my method  like so

```
int frequency[MAX_SYMBOLS] = {0};
```

MAX_SYMBOLS is defined as being 255. I then read over the and try to count every time a particular character appears below is my method set_frequency()

```
void set_frequency()
{

    int count = 0;
    char c;
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
      if(c != ' ' && c != '\n')
      {
             frequency[(int) c]++;
             count++;
      }
    }

    fclose(fp);

  }
```

iam currently getting a segmentation fault for this not entirely sure why?
I think its an issue with the array index. or possibly the size of my file as it is rather large. If anyone can help that would be great as iam not great with c to be honest.

### EDIT

the 'c' variable need to be an int not a char as that is what is returned from the fgetc() function. then I wont have to cast in the index value!!

Comment: `c` will never equal `EOF` because `EOF` doesn't fit in a `char`. Change `c` to `int` and you also won't need the cast anymore.

Comment: i thought this was relatively commond c syntax for END OF FILE!? pretty sure its used in the K & R book a whole bunch!

Comment: Yes, and it's also commonly noted that it requires an `int`. `fgetc()` returns an `int` as well. That's a hint.

Comment: @user1232726 it is, but if you read carefully you'll notice they use `int`s to read characters as well.

Comment: ah yes! that was pretty dumb. its an int!

Comment: awesome. i was even using gdb there and couldnt figure out what was up

Comment: Note: C does not support [methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)). You are using functions. There is a fundamental difference between methods and functions.

Comment: Use `int c; ... frequency[UCHAR_MAX + 1] ... frequency[c]++;`

Comment: You did not have to cast the index for an array. If `char` is signed, that will result in _undefined behaviour_ for int, too (the conversion is done automatically anyway. For what you write, I'd strongly recommend to read about the standard types, `char` and _integer promotions_. There might be some missunderstanding on your side - no offence.

Comment: yeah. i have it as an 'int' now. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the fact that `EOF` could not fit in a `char`, you have 2 potential problems:

1. MAX_SYMBOLS is smaller than 255, that are the character you can find using plane ascii.
2. **`char` is a signed integer**. If you read something > 0x7f it will be converted in a negative array index.

Try using an integer for reading to satisfy requirement for EOF. You'll also get guarantee that the code will never be negative, but in the range 0-255.

```
void set_frequency()
{

    int count = 0;
    int c;
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
      if(c != ' ' && c != '\n')
      {
             frequency[c]++;
             count++;
      }
    }

    fclose(fp);

  }
```

If happens that you have to use chars for similar issues use cast to force unsigned values:

```
frequency[(int)(unsigned char) c]++;
```